# Search multiple MySQL tables

Tags: mysql

I use five tables to store project data. When creating a new job, I first want my script to search to see if a project with the same project number exists. Each of these tables uses a column "project_number" as an index key

Here is what I've tried to use to search the five tables at once, however it fails to return results I know are there.

```
$check_project_number = "SELECT * FROM project_details WHERE project_number = ?
                UNION
                    SELECT * FROM project_crews WHERE project_number = ?
                UNION
                    SELECT * FROM project_tooling WHERE project_number = ?
                UNION
                    SELECT * FROM project_scope WHERE project_number = ?
                UNION
                    SELECT * FROM project_equipment WHERE project_number = ?";

$q_check_project_number = $conn->prepare($check_project_number);
    $q_check_project_number ->execute(array($project_number,$project_number,$project_number,$project_number,$project_number));
        $project_count = $q_check_project_number ->rowCount();

            if ($project_count > 0) /*if a user exists*/
                {
                    print "project exists";
                }   

            else
            { /*insert records*/
```

Comment: Are you receiving any errors? Are you sure the data exists in the table(s)? Does it work when querying against a single table, or just two instead of all 5?

Comment: replace `*` with `project_number` . Reason: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `UNION`, the columns specified in the `SELECT` statements need to all match across all of the different queries you are using the `UNION` tag on.  if any of them are different, it will fail.  My assumption is that one or more of the tables you are querying has either 1) column(s) that do not exist in other tables, or 2) column names that are different

EXAMPLE (of course, change the select clause to match the column names you need to pull from your table(s):

```
SELECT project_id, project_number, project_name FROM project_details WHERE project_number = ?
UNION
SELECT project_id, project_number, project_name FROM project_crews WHERE project_number = ?
UNION
SELECT project_id, project_number, project_name FROM project_tooling WHERE project_number = ?
UNION
SELECT project_id, project_number, project_name FROM project_scope WHERE project_number = ?
UNION
SELECT project_id, project_number, project_name FROM project_equipment WHERE project_number = ?
```